# How to copy hbase data

Tags: copy, hbase

I need to copy data from one cluster to another cluster. I did some research and found I could do copyTable, which basically scan and put data from one to another.

I also know that I can copy over the whole HDFS volume for Hhase. I am wondering if this works and if perform better than copyTable? (I believe it should perform better since it copy files without logic operations)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HBase replication](http://hbase.apache.org/replication.html) you can find a short  how to [here](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/replication/package-summary.html#requirements)